# Symfony2 form choice field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `Product` and a `Category` entity.

`Category` entity is a adjacency list/materialized-path model.

`Product` has a relation to `Category` which has a relation back to `Product`

In my `ProductType` class I would like a selectmenu with all categories at a specific level grouped by parent name.

```
$builder->add('category', 'entity', array(
            'label'    => 'Category',
            'class'    => 'Test\AdminBundle\Entity\Category',
            'property' => 'name',
            'group_by' => 'parentName',
            'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {

                $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('c');

                return $qb->where($qb->expr()->like('c.path', ':path'))
                        ->orderBy('c.path', 'ASC')
                        ->setParameter('path', '%/%/%');
            },
    ));
```

`Category` got a `getParentName` method:

```
public function getParentName()
{
    if (null === $this->getParent()) {
    return null;
    }

    return $this->getParent()->getName();
}
```

It works as expected but a query is executed for every parent (a lot). If I make a join with parent the parent will also be selectable in the selectmenu which I don't want.

How do I limit the queries?

Or filter a joined result?

Comment: Add can add `->leftJoin('c.parent', 'p')` if you have one parent for category. This does not affect the number of results

Comment: I understand what you mean but unfortunately it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I was not fetchjoining... adding a select to the querybuilder made it work:

```
$qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('c');

return $qb->select('c, p')
->leftJoin('c.parent', 'p')
->where($qb->expr()->like('c.path', ':path'))
->orderBy('c.path', 'ASC')
->setParameter('path', '%/%/%');
```